# Tab Control - Changing to different forms (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a tab control on a blank form, although when I change tabs is there a way of changing the form when clicking on a different tab. See below for clarification:

[image: Tab Control]

E.g. If I clicked "tabPage2" I would be presented with Form2.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Just make Form2 borderless and change TopLevel to False, and then you can add it to the tabPage2.Controls collection like a normal form.  Probably add DockStyle to Fill for that form, too.

Simple demo:

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) {
  if (e.TabPage.Name == tabPage2.Name) {
    if (tabPage2.Controls.Count == 0) {
      Form f = new Form();
      f.TopLevel = false;
      f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
      f.BackColor = Color.Red;
      f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      tabPage2.Controls.Add(f);
      f.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little bit strange question and to my mind not the best design practice. As for me I wiould suggest you to create UserControls and to place them at any form/tab/container. It will provide you same behaviour everywhere.

BTW you can place any form inside the container for ex:

```
tabPage2.Controls.Add(new Form2());
```

Comment: Your example will throw an argument exception since by default a new Form has TopLevel = true.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into a dockable forms control like the open source [DockPanelSuite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/).   With this control, you can have a form host multiple forms, in tabs, or docked like Visual Studio.